# Multiple hostnames, same domain, different virtualhost

Tags: apache2

I am trying to route requests to different docroots depending on the HOST name (not domain name):

```
 <VirtualHost 123.123.12.12:80>
 SuexecUserGroup "#521" "#521"
 ServerName forum.somesite.net
 DocumentRoot /home/somesite/public_html/forums
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost 123.123.12.12:80>
 SuexecUserGroup "#521" "#521"
 ServerName www.somesite.net
 DocumentRoot /home/somesite/public_html
 </VirtualHost>
```

It is not working though.  Apache seems to go to the first entry regardless of what is in the hostname.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the end I found that NameVirtualHost was not set for the IP (123.123.12.12 in my example). Once I set that, it began to route the requests properly. I have been using virtualmin to add sites, not sure why it doesn't use the NameVirtualHost directive but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second Virtual host to this

```
 <VirtualHost 123.123.12.12:80>
  SuexecUserGroup "#521" "#521"
  ServerName somesite.net
  ServerAlias www.somesite.net
  DocumentRoot /home/somesite/public_html
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Also are these virtualhost defined in different files in sites_enabled directory ?

Comment: That did not change anything.  If I reorder the directives I just end up going to the first one in the line, not the second..

Comment: In the end I found that NameVirtualHost was not set for the IP (123.123.12.12 in my example).  Once I set that, it began to route the requests properly.  I have been using virtualmin to add sites, not sure why it doesn't use the NameVirtualHost directive but it doesn't.